# How can I JSDoc my enumify "enums"?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Using the [Enumify library](https://github.com/rauschma/enumify).

I want to document the enums I create, e.g.,

```
import { Enum } from 'enumify';

class CMD extends Enum {};

CMD.initEnum({
  REBOOT: { byte: 0x00 },
  SLEEP:  { byte: 0x01 },
});

export default CMD;
```

In mainline code they're accessed like this:

```
import CMD from './command';

console.log(CMD.REBOOT);
```

Since the enums are attached to `CMD`, and created during the `initEnum` call,
there's no way to embed the definition inside the creation.

The only workaround I've been able to come up with is to pull out the values,
document each `const`, and use the values in `initEnum`:

```
/** Some doc */
const REBOOT = { byte: 0x00 };

/** More doc */
const SLEEP  = { byte: 0x01 };

CMD.initEnum({
  REBOOT,
  SLEEP,
});
```

This isn't awful, but it does not make the hierarchy clear, e.g., it's CMD.REBOOT
to the outside world.

Using `@name` fails because I cannot embed the enum's "container" in the name
without quoting it, and quotes show up in the docs. I also have to tag it with
something that it really isn't so JSDoc knows how to document it:

```
/**
 * @name 'CMD.REBOOT'
 * @global
 */
```

Are there any other options? I just need to indicate in the docs that they exist, preferably with low overhead since
they're often just simple values that we don't even care about.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired `@lends`? It seems legit to document static members like that

```
CMD.initEnum(/** @lends CMD */{
  REBOOT: { byte: 0x00 },
  SLEEP:  { byte: 0x01 },
});
```

Comment: This seems promising--but I cannot figure out the magic incantation to avoid getting duplicate entries for both the `CMD` class (I've also tried using `@namespace`) *and* the individual members. I don't even know how many combinations I've tried, probably at least a dozen or two :( I may have to move away from JSDoc.